# NullPointerException при использовании GSON в onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, gson

Добрый день!

Делаю тестовое погодное приложение и беру данные в OpenWeatherApi. Получение данных перевожу в AsyncTask и в методе onPostExecute хочу использовать GSON, чтобы создать на их основе новый объект.

Когда отдельно применяю GSON - все работает. Стоит мне положить его в onPostExecute - все ломается и выдает

```
 lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

[image: Целиком ошибка выглядит вот так.]

Последнее, что выполняет программа - отображает в Log полученную строку с данными в формате JSON. Команда как раз прописана в onPostExecute.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так — посмотрел уже много подобных примеров и вроде как должно все работать.

Ниже прилагаю свой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;

//создаю классы для размещения данных

public class Weather {

    public Main main;
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public int code;

    public void Weather () {
        Main main = new Main();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public float temp;
    public int humidity;
    public int pressure;
    public float tempMax;
    public float tempMin;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

//вызываю асинхронный поток и даю ему ссылку

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=42b48587e1a4e48a2e14c453899f9cc4");
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result="";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1){
                char ch = (char) data;
                result += ch;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.i("Result", result);

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        weather = gson.fromJson(result, Weather.class);

        Log.i("Name", weather.name);
        Log.i("ТЕмпература", String.valueOf((weather.main.temp - 30)*5/9));

        textView.setText(String.valueOf((weather.main.temp - 30) * 5 / 9));

    }
}


}
```

Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: на какой строчке именно падает?

Comment: в `weather` по всей видимости не инициализированы поля

Comment: у вас неправильная структура класса

Comment: @ermak0ff - попробовал - не помогло. Когда отдельно GSON запускал - он не требовал их инициализации

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас неправильная структура класса, по скрину в `JSON` у Вас есть ключ `city` который является родителем для `Weather`.
Добавьте класс

```
public class City {

    public Weather city;
 }
```

После чего подставьте его в `GSON` вместо `Weather`

Ошибка NPE сваливается при доступе к `weather.name`

```
Log.i("Name", weather.name);
```

Опять же ввиду того, что у Вас неправильная структура класса.

Comment: Спасибо - я не обратил внимание - у меня там ссылка для просмотра погоды на несколько дней вперед - поэтому он возвращает не те сведения, которые заполнят класс - невнимательность - всё заработало)

Answer (score 3):

У Вас написана же причина ошибки:

> NullPointerException : println needs a message

в методе`onPostExecute`, из чего можно предположить(ведь мы не знаем что там у Вас находится в строке MainActivity.java:95) что ошибка в этой строке:

```
Log.i("Name", weather.name);
```

Переменная `weather` инициализирована, а вот за ее полe `name`, по всей видимости нет, что и приводит к `NPE`.